# Run PHP function in While Loop

Tags: php, function, loops, while-loop

I'd like to run a function within a While loop.
Unfortunately, it works but not quite as desired.

My goal is to read out from a CSV file, each line and is stored in the MySQL database. This also works flawlessly.

In addition, however, I want to let miteinpflegen a value by a numeric random.

Here again my scripts to generate the numerical codes.

```
function generateCode($length){
$string = "";
$numbers = "0123456789";
    for($i=0;$i < $length;$i++) {
        $char = $numbers[mt_rand(0, strlen($numbers)-1)];
        $string .= $char;
    }
return $string;
}
$gencode = generateCode(8);
```

Works great.

And here my while loop ($handle is in my case the var to open CSV file)

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $import = "INSERT into jobs(id,link_id,random number) values('NULL','$linkid','$gencode')";
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

But how do I get it back now that each line of the CSV file gets its own random number or rather, which is calculated in each row $gencode new?
At the moment i get one random number for all rows.

For help, I am very grateful.
I just can no longer see the forest for the trees.

Thank you

Comment: _how do I get it back now that each line of the CSV file gets its own random number_ move `$gencode = generateCode(8);` inside the loop

Comment: Hello. I have solved the problem already own. As I thought. I was too long on it and then have overlooked something.
One should not pack doe entire function in the While Loop only "$gencode = generateCode (8);"
Thus, the entire while loop should look like this.
while (($data = fgetcsv ($ handle, 10000, ";")) == FALSE) {
$gencode = generateCode (8);
     $ import = "INSERT into jobs (id, link_id, randomnumber) values ('NULL', '$ linkid', '$gencode')";
     mysql_query ($ import) or die (mysql_error ());
}

Comment: @SkysTheLimit_81 - If one of the answers bellow has helped you, please select it as the answer for your question, otherwise if you found the solution yourself you can post it as an answer and later accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call your own function `generateCode()` like any other function inside your loop:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $gencode = generateCode(8);

    // the rest of your code

}
```

Just make sure that `generateCode()` is already defined when you call it.